# Autoscroll PyQT QTextWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

How can I **autoscroll** to the bottom of my `QTextEdit`

in my GUI init function

```
self.mytext = QTextEdit()
self.cursor = QTextCursor(self.mytext.document())
self.mytext.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
```

and how I am adding to it in another function

```
self.cursor.insertText(str(self.user) + ": " + str(self.line.text()) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`moveCursor`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextedit.html#moveCursor) method should do that. e.g.:

```
self.mytext.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

Answer (score 8):

I've found the following to work:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

self.display = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
self.display.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
    self.display.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```
self.mytext.ensureCursorVisible()
```