# In QT "ui->scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(0)" has no effect

Tags: c++, qt, scrollview, qtwidgets

So in my UI designer I have a ScrollArea Widget, I then in my MainWindow.cpp, I create a QGraphicScene and a QGraphics View. I create a new widget and give that widget a QVBoxLayout so that it will auto-size(which is correct to my understanding).

I then use `ui->scrollArea->setWidget(widget);` to make this new widget the child of my scrollView.

All of this seems correct because I have scroll bars that I can navigate my scene with. However; using the line `ui->scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(0);` still has no effect on the scroll bar values.

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene();
scene->setSceneRect(0,0,2500,2500);
view = new QGraphicsView(scene);

QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
view->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::white);
QVBoxLayout* bLayout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(widget);

bLayout->addWidget(view);

widget->show();

ui->scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
```

Comment: Maybe the scroll bars that you see don't belong to `ui->scrollArea`, but to the `view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure to address the correct scrollbar (as pointed in the comments by thuga), maybe check if your scroll area is modified after that init. I mean I'm not sure of the bahaviour, but if you modified some text in your widget for example, I think the scrollbar will be impacted.

You may need to catch some of your widget's event to reapply those:

```
ui->scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
```

If it doesn't help, you should try to debug by tracking scrollbar value with

```
ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->value()
```

and see if your set is well applied, and maybe when it is overriden

Just in case, you may also try some of the methods indicated here, but it's probably not relevant to your issue: [setValue of ScrollBar Don't work at first time](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/42252-setValue-of-ScrollBar-Don-t-work-at-first-time)

Comment: Yeah I think I could be using the 'wrong' scroll bars, the value never changes from 0 :/ But then that makes no sense to me, I don't understand where these bars could have come from, they control the widget perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I just had the this problem. Then, after debugging with `ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->value()` I realized that the scrolling area has no size before the component is show on the screen, i.e., it does not change the scrolling because it is not visible yet.

This is a sample Python code, but the is the same for C++, except the Language Syntax.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
...

    dialog = QDialog()
    ...

    verticalScrollBar = dialog.QPlainTextEdit.verticalScrollBar()
    horizontalScrollBar = dialog.QPlainTextEdit.horizontalScrollBar()

    # Has no effect, if you print the values, you will see always 0
    verticalScrollBar.setValue( horizontalScrollBar.maximum() )
    horizontalScrollBar.setValue( horizontalScrollBar.minimum() )

    dialog.show()

    # Now it has effect
    verticalScrollBar.setValue( horizontalScrollBar.maximum() )
    horizontalScrollBar.setValue( horizontalScrollBar.minimum() )
```

1. [Autoscroll PyQT QTextWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778726/autoscroll-pyqt-qtextwidget)